# NodeMCU 12E power requirement

Tags: nodemcu

On the back of the NodeMCU, it is: **`Vin +5V Recommended +10V MAX`**. I can see that it has an AMS1117 voltage regulator. Its [datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) says we can use [4.5V to 15V]
[image]

AmI reading something wrong?

- Can I use 12V for VCC?
- Can I use 15V for VCC?

Comment: found answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512879/15v-to-3-3v-to-power-esp12e

Comment: 12V is ok, but not 15V

Comment: Does this answer your question? [15V to 3.3V to power ESP12E](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512879/15v-to-3-3v-to-power-esp12e)

Answer (score 0):

"Am I reading something wrong" - you are reading the wrong datasheet. You are dealing with the NodeMCU and the only data that is relevant for you is the data in its datasheet. It doesn't matter what the AMS1117 datasheet says, because the specs given there depend on the actual application. Only the designers of the NodeMCU know how much current it will sink and how much power it can dissipate. Those people have certainly read the AMS1117's datasheet as well and know its capabilities. They must have had a reason to rate the board like they did. You need to consider table 1 of the mentioned datasheet, where thermal resistance is covered. But you don't know the thermal resistance of the NodeMCU board and its layout.